# ionic framework "start: Unknown job: myApp"

Tags: ionic-framework, startup

I just start on [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) framework. I setup required dependency. But while creating with new sample mentioned as `ionic start myApp tabs` it responding with following output: "**start: Unknown job: myApp**". Any suggestion here, if I'm missing something !